# TypeScript return object declared after or before

Tags: typescript

I've seen examples of where the expected returned object in TypeScript is either:

Declared at the start:

```
export const Text2 : React.FunctionComponent = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="text">{props.children}</div>
    )
}
```

See how `React.FunctionComponent` as the expected return is declared immediately after the method name `Text2` and then then parentheses and params follow afterwards.

Or the declared at the end instead:

```
export const Text2 = ({ text = '' }) : JSX.Element => {
    return (
        <div className="text">{text}</div>
    );
}
```

See how `JSX.Element` as the expected return is declared right at the very end with the parentheses and params coming before...

What's the difference here? **Please excuse the use of props children over parameters in the examples... I know the difference between use children and the attributes!** The question I'm asking is the difference between the location of the expected return part.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you have a variable `Text2` with an explicit type `React.FunctionComponent`

In the second example, you don't specify the type of the variable, you specify the return type of the assigned function, which is `{text: ''} => JSX.Element`.

In practice they're essentially the same for React, it's just a function that takes an object and return a JSX element.

If you want more information, check https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet#function-components

Answer (score 1):

Each one is specifying the type on a different thing.

The first one is specifying the type of the variable `Text2`, which is a variable holding a `React.FunctionComponent`.  It doesn't really say anything about the return type of the function, but a `React.FunctionComponent` generally expects to return a `JSX.Element` which this function does so TypeScript sees no problems.

The basic structure is simply:

```
const VariableName : VariableType = Something;
```

The second one is specifying the return type of the function, which is `JSX.Element`.  TypeScript doesn't really care about `React.FunctionComponent` in this case, you're simply declaring a function which returns a `JSX.Element` and assigning that function to a variable.

The structure here is more like:

```
const VariableName = () : ReturnType => { /* function body */ };
```

Note that you can also specify both:

```
export const Text2 : React.FunctionComponent = (props) : JSX.Element => {
    return (
        <div className="text">{props.children}</div>
    );
}
```

TypeScript will try to infer the type where it's not specified.  In this particular assignment statement (assigning a function to a `const`) there are a couple places to explicitly specify types.  Both aren't necessary if one can be inferred from the other.

---

**Edit:** Based on comments below from the original combined example in this answer, the combined version which has `{ text = '' }` as the function argument would be more like:

```
export const Text2 : React.FC<any> = ({ text = '' }) : JSX.Element => {
    return (
        <div className="text">{text}</div>
    );
}
```

Of course this is relying on `any`, which is generally frowned upon because at that point you're basically telling TypeScript to not use TypeScript :)  But if you have a defined type which includes `text` then that would work as well:

```
export interface SomeType {
    text: string;
}

export const Text2 : React.FC<SomeType> = ({ text = '' }) : JSX.Element => {
    return (
        <div className="text">{text}</div>
    );
}
```

The type can of course have more properties, it just needs at least a `string` property called `text` to satisfy the argument to the function being assigned to `Text2`.

Comment: `React.FunctionComponent = ({ text = '' })` gives the error: `Property 'text' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'`

Comment: @Cameron: Interesting.  Admittedly I don't have a testable environment handy.  You may need to specify a generic type for the function component.  Something like: `export const Text2 : React.FC<any> = ({ text = '' }) : JSX.Element => { /* ... */ }`  And then can replace `any` with any specific type that includes a field called `text`.

Comment: using `export const Text4 = ({ text = ''}) : React.FunctionComponent => (props) : JSX.Element` works. So seems you need to use a rocket `=>` instead.

Comment: @Cameron: That's a strange approach, but may not be doing what you think it's doing.  (Though the result may be the same so it still works.)  In that example you're not specifying the type for `Text4`, which makes it more like the second example in the original question.  What's being assigned to `Text4` is a function that accepts any type that has a `text` property and returns a `React.FunctionComponent`, and that function is returning a function that accepts `props` and returns a `JSX.Element`.  It's just increasing the function nesting and adding confusion.

Comment: By works... I mean it removed that error... it didn't actually work in practice haha.

Comment: @Cameron: In practice it was likely expecting an invocation of the return value, which itself would return the expected value.  I think the `React.FC<SomeType>` is the necessary type for the `const` variable in this case, where `SomeType` has a property called `text`.

Comment: I'd love to see a working example of what you mean if you get chance.

Comment: @Cameron: I've updated the answer.  It's still very free-hand code, just going off of recent memory from code at work.